# Is there any way to install applications onto a shared hosting account?

Tags: shared-hosting, web-applications

I've got a shared hosting account with arvixe.com.  I wanted to move my Gemini install from a server in my spare bedroom to my hosting account so I can access it over the web.

Unfortunately the Gemini application is only installable by means of an .exe file ([www.geminiplatform.com/download](http://www.geminiplatform.com/download)) and as I don't have RDP access to the hosting machine I can't just click 'n run. Has anyone got a workaround for this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask the host if they'll install it but the odds are they won't as they don't want to risk messing up the server for one shared hosting client. If you need custom software on your server then you need to look into a dedicated server or a VPS. You can install and configure those servers any way you need to as it only affects you. Of course those plans cost a lot more then shared hosting does.

Comment: Thanks. I did ask their support guys and they weren't overly keen/helpful. They've suggested I install it locally then sync files and databases over manually to their end.